# How to configure HTTP request headers for a Canvas app

Tags: httprequest, canvas

I’m trying to create a Canvas app where the URL is served by a CDN. Salesforce is setting 'cache-control: no-cache' in the request header and this is causing the request to fail with status 403 along with a message that only cacheable requests are supported.

Is there a way to configure the cache-control header in the request that Salesforce generates?

Thanks.